# What will happen to a multicolumn index (Composite) when one of the column is dropped in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, indexing

I have columnA, ColumnB in a table and a composite index formed with these 2 columns.
Now I am removing ColumnB from table.
What will happen to the index now?
Should I recreate the index now again with ColumnA alone.

Comment: Can't you try this on a test table?

Comment: Thanks @Aleksej I have tried em.. got the same result. It is required to recreate the index. When dropping a column all its associated indexes also get dropped.

Comment: Right. That is what you would expect, after all.. how could an index exist and refer to a non existing column?

Comment: @Aleksej you are absolutely right... But it was behaving in different ways across machines (This may be due to some caching). 
It removed the index and was unable to create a new index with same name as it suggests same index exists. 
But it worked fine in another machine.

This makes me to post the query for an expert opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple test:

```
SQL> create table t (c1 number, c2 number);

Table created.

SQL> create index i on t(c1, c2);

Index created.

SQL> select index_name
  2  from user_indexes
  3  where table_name = 'T';

INDEX_NAME
------------------------------
I

SQL> alter table t drop column c2;

Table altered.

SQL> select index_name
  2  from user_indexes
  3  where table_name = 'T';

no rows selected

SQL>
```